# How to validate DTO string field is one of specified values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

My spring boot application has a DTO class for creating a task.

```java
public class CreateTaskDTO {
     
    @NotBlank
    private String status;
}
```

I want the `type` field to be one of these values: "DONE", "IN_PROGRESS", "OPEN".

Is there hibernate constraints or any other workarounds I can validate thie field?

Comment: How about using enum adding @JsonValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum Status() {
    DONE, IN_PROGRESS, OPEN
}

public class CreateTaskDTO {
    @NotNull
    private Status status;
}
```

Enum must be created. The created enum should also be used in the DTO.